# <trust level="Full" /> error on godaddy server

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have uploaded website on godaddy web server.On localhost it is working fine but on web server it  is showing me an error like this

```
    Configuration Error
```

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

```
   Line 24:     </compilation>
   Line 25: 
   Line 26:     <trust level="Full" />    
   Line 27: 
   Line 28:   </system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to get around this issue was to do a **Clean**, **Rebuild**, and **redeploy all files** to GoDaddy.

If you're using GoDaddy's Classic Hosting and running ASP.NET 4.0/4.5, then the default trust level is Full, and you need the `<trust level="Full" />` config entry as specified in the OP's question.

More info can be found [here](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/2531/what-trust-level-can-i-use-when-running-asp-net).